# Working on a PR for DefinitelyTyped. How can I fix "Cannot find module 'csstype'" when I run "npm run lint markdown-to-jsx"?

Tags: typescript, definitelytyped

Here’s what I have done so far following the instructions on https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped#verifying.

I forked https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped.

I git cloned my fork and ran `npm install`.

I updated the type definitions and tests of `types/markdown-to-jsx`.

Now, running `npm run lint markdown-to-jsx` returns an error.

Why?

```sh
npm run lint markdown-to-jsx

> definitely-typed@0.0.3 lint /Users/sunknudsen/tmp/DefinitelyTyped
> dtslint types "markdown-to-jsx"

Error: Errors in typescript@next for external dependencies:
../react/index.d.ts(34,22): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'csstype'.
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try `npm install` within `types/<your-package-name>`, in your case:

```js
cd types/markdown-to-jsx && npm i;
```

? It should fix it.

If it doesn't, you might just have some dependencies somewhere along the tree that also need to be installed. I see that these are typings for `markdown-to-jsx`, so I would suggest to also run `npm i` in the types folder of `react`, `react-dom`, and `react-markdown`.

I was running into a similar issue, and running it in `types/react` (in addition to running it in my project's types of course) solved it:

```js
cd types/react && npm i
```

Comment: This seems to work. Also, I think they've added a feature that is able to detect this sometimes and show a message ([(dtslint) Adds a message telling you to npm install when there's missing deps](https://github.com/microsoft/dtslint/pull/319)). In that feature, they use this format although I think it does the same thing: `npm install --prefix types/react`. This might also be related: [(dtslint) Needs to install npm dependancies of local type dependencies](https://github.com/microsoft/dtslint/issues/226)